# If I give this controller 48 V, 20 A, will it cause damage?

Tags: power, batteries, amplifier, dc, controller

I have a DC power supply that outputs 48 V, 20 A. The bike controller says it works on 36 V and 48 ​​V, and 23 A as a maximum.

Are these 23 A in the case of 48 V, or in the case of 36 V? I'm afraid the controller will burn if I connect 48 V and 20 A.

Controller data sheet:
[image: controller data sheet]

Converter power supply:
[image: **converter power supply **]

Power supply data sheet:
[image: power supply data sheet]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142070/discussion-on-question-by-matrix43-if-i-give-this-controller-48-v-20-a-will-it).

Comment: This looks operating a "48 V controller&motor" on a 12 V battery&step-up converter. *Bad* idea, more so for a mobile solution.

Comment: @greybeard you mean it will not work??

Comment: It will work no better than a brushed 12 V motor - for much investment into contemporary electronics.

Comment: @greybeard I don't have enough space for a 48V battery so I came up with this idea

Comment: Edit information that invites useful answers in your question, such as space available, types of motor that can be put to use, batteries at hand ("full" spec), - whatever helps.

Comment: The controller might not burn due to the fact it could ingest up to 23 A. The question is, what your DC supply will do should the controller consumer 23 A. It might switch of, reduce the voltage, burn, or what ever (data sheet needed). Depending on this the controller might simply not work as expected. If you never draw the maximum power from the controller so that it does not need to ingest more than 20 A there should be not problem. BUT: still too little detail to tell for sure.

Comment: By the way, the 23 A are in my opinion for both voltages!

Comment: @All - Earlier comments were already moved to chat, but comments have continued here. That's a problem as it splits the info which might help someone to write an answer (and to understand additional clarifications etc.) across both places. We can't move comments to chat a second time on one Q and keep the original owner. Therefore I'm locking comments (only) on this Q, so that further *comments* can't be added. Continue clarification in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142070). [Edit] the question to add relevant updates. Answers can be written, when someone has enough info.